# How to build dataframe from cobol and ebcdic file with COMP fields using Cobrix?

Tags: dataframe, cobol, comp-3

I am trying first to build a simple dataframe from mainframe source with [cobrix](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix) to find out how it deals with ebcdic files.

My Input looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54zQ7.png). (hex) : 313030100C3230301A0C. If I quickly open with Notepad++ : [raw_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkhMu.jpg)

I use these [options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfFE5.png) to read my data and turn it into a dataframe.
I have tried all the ebcdic encoding supported values without success. I also tried to change `S9(3).` to `999.` or `9(3).` in .cobol file but does not change anything.

My [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G9Wz.png) does not look like what I was [expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESJPz.png).

It works fine with "classic" ascii encodage and without "COMP-3".
Can you help me to find out why my df does not look like expected ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Please paste your code inline instead of using screenshots.

Comment: The data example you provide is ascii and not ebcdic. I would of thought it would be a binary file (it is classified as text in the option file). The data looks like valid ASCII with comp-3 fields in it. EBCDIC to ASCII conversions often corrupt binary data fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data has been converted from EBCDIC to ASCII already.

The first s9(3) characters '100' should be hex 'F1F0F0' in EBCDIC.

However your file was transferred it converted all bytes to ASCII therefore corrupting the comp-3 values which are NOT valid EBCDIC.